# Storing data through HTTP PUT method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, postman, put

This is my HTTP PUT method. This code is not giving any exceptions but still not storing data in database can anyone please help. Model is my getter setters class.

```
[HttpPut]
        public HttpResponseMessage Addfood(int id,[FromBody] Model model)
        {
            Food food = new Food();
            var userid = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);
            if (userid == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No Record Found");
            }

            food.UID = id;
            food.Name = model.Foodname;
            food.Price = model.Foodprice;
            food.Image = model.Foodimage;
            food.Date_Time = DateTime.Today;
            Category category = new Category();
            category.Name = model.Categoryname;
            db.Categories.Add(category);
            food.CatID = category.ID;
            db.Foods.Add(food);
            db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, food);
        }
    }
```

My Database tables.

```
 [dbo].[Food](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [Image] [image] NULL,
        [Price] [varchar](10) NULL,
        [CatID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [UID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Date/Time] [datetime] NULL,


[dbo].[Category](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,

[dbo].[User](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Phone] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [AID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Date/time] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsVerify] [bit] NULL,
    [ProfilePicture] [image] NULL,
```

When i am hitting this request through postman.these are the params which i am giving in postman.

```
{"Foodname":"Bir","Foodprice":210,"Categoryname":"H000"}
```

i am getting this but my database is not updating. I use this method with post call also but still not working

```
{
    "ID": 0,
    "Name": "Bir",
    "Image": null,
    "Price": "210",
    "CatID": 0,
    "UID": 52,
    "Date_Time": "2018-12-05T00:00:00+05:00",
    "Category": null,
    "User": {
        "ID": 52,
        "Name": "h999",
        "Phone": 3332158086,
        "Email": "a.b.c@yahooooo.com",
        "AID": 36,
        "Password": "030021",
        "Date_time": "2018-12-05T03:26:13.82",
        "IsVerify": null,
        "ProfilePicture": null,
        "Address": null,
        "Flags": [],
        "Foods": [],
        "Order_Tracking": [],
        "Order_Tracking1": []
    },
    "FoodRecommendations": [],
    "Order_Tracking": [],
    "Ratings": []
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  What exactly is stopping a user from updating other information?  What information are they updating and how is it failing?  And what does this code have to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if *any* user has this email:

```
if (db.Users.Any(x => x.Email == model.Email))
```

But it sounds like you want to check if *any other* user has this email.  Perhaps something like this:

```
if (db.Users.Any(x => x.Id != id && x.Email == model.Email))
```